# Why is the Hodge conjecture equivalent to the assertion that $ \mathcal{R}_{ \mathrm{Hodge} } $ is fully faithfull?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, hodge-theory

On pages 17 and 18 of the following document: https://www.math.tifr.res.in/~sujatha/ihes.pdf, we find the following paragraph:

> Let $ \mathbb{Q} \mathrm{HS}$ be the category of pure Hodge structures over $\mathbb{Q}$.
>   There is a functor:
>   $$
> \mathcal{R}_{ \mathrm{Hodge} }  \colon  \mathop{\mathrm{Mot}}^{ \bullet }_{ \mathrm{num} } ( k, \mathbb{Q} ) \to \mathbb{Q} \mathrm{HS} 
> $$
>   and the Hodge conjecture is equivalent to the assertion that $\mathcal{R}_{ \mathrm{Hodge} }$ is fully faithful.

My questions are:

How is the Hodge realization functor $ \mathcal{R}_{ \mathrm{Hodge} }$ explicitly defined? And how to prove explicitly that the Hodge conjecture is equivalent to the assertion that $\mathcal{R}_{\mathrm{Hodge}}$ is fully faithful?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The exact same question was posted a couple days ago on mathoverflow : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267758/why-is-the-hodge-conjecture-equivalent-to-the-assertion-that-mathcalr-ma . It has been answered in the comments. If it requires more explanation, tell us what was unclear !

Comment: I don't know how $ \mathcal{R}_{\mathrm{Hodge}} $ is defined. I need a complete answer.

Comment: But, as said in the comments, you have a well defined functor $\mathcal{V}_k\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\mathrm{HS}$ which send a variety $X$ to the sum $\bigoplus H^i(X,\mathbb{Q})$ equipped with the canonical Hodge structure and graduation. This functor can be extended to correspondences, then (we are working under the assumption that numerical and homological equivalence agree), the functor factor through $Cor_{num}(k,\mathbb{Q})$. Then, it factors through the pseudo-abelianization (because $\mathbb{Q}\mathrm{HS})$ is abelian), and finally it factor through $\mathcal{R}_{\mathrm{Hodge}}$.

Comment: because the Lefschetz motive $\mathbb{L}$ is sent to $H^2(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{Q})$ which is invertible for $\otimes$ in the category of pure Hodge structure. At every step, we use the universal property of the construction (correspondences, quotient, pseudo-abelianization, inversion of the Lefschetz motive)

Comment: Which definition of Hodge structure do you use please ?. I'm a beginner in this field. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I don't think there are several definitions : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_structure .

Comment: Thank you very much.  :-) Why is the Hodge conjecture equivalent to the fact that $ \mathcal{R}_{ \mathrm{Hodge}} $ is fully faithfull ?

Comment: Do you know what are the morphisms in the category of motives ? Because this is really not hard to see why the Hodge conjecture is equivalent to the Hodge realization functor to be full. You should be able to prove it for yourself. At least, show your try, and we will see where you have some difficulties.

Comment: It's hard for me as just a beginner in this field. Morphisms in $ \mathrm{Mot}_{ \sim } ( k, \mathbb{Q} ) $ are defined by : $ \mathrm{Mot}_{ \sim } ( k, \mathbb{Q} ) ( \ (h(X) , p ) \ , \ ( h(Y), q ) \ ) = q \circ \mathrm{Corr}_{ \sim } ( h(X ) \ , \ h(Y) ) \circ p $ ... $ \mathcal{R}_{ \mathrm{Hodge} } $ is fully faithfull means that : $ \mathrm{Mot}_{ \sim } ( k, \mathbb{Q} ) ( ( h(X) , p ) \ , \ h(Y) , q ) \simeq \mathrm{Hom} ( H^* ( X ) , H^* (Y) ) = H^* ( X \times Y ) $, right ?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean, it is your Hodge realization functor that is not quite right. It sends $(h(X),p)$ to the direct summand of $H(X)$ defined by the projector $p$. But, this direct summand stuff is really not meaningful for Hodge conjecture. With this, you almost have the implication $\mathcal{R}_{\mathrm{Hodge}}$ full $\Rightarrow$ Hodge conjecture (by the way, the fact that the Hodge realization is faithful depends on the choice of the homological equivalence, or the numerical equivalence under the assumption that $\sim_{Hom}=\sim_{num}$.)

Comment: Can you please write me an answer much more detailed, from A to Z It's really hard for me to do it, although you try to give me indications. Because this is not an exercice. It's a part of my course which i have to understand it not to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I'll do it tomorrow. But even if it is not an exercise, you are doing hard mathematics and if you have questions like these, you should really try to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is a recap of how the category of motives is constructed :

- First consider the category $\mathcal{V}_k$ of smooth projective varieties over $k$.
- Add morphisms to this category by adding all correspondances.
- Add formal kernel and images of projectors.
- The motive of $\mathbb{P}^1$ then decomposes as $\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{L}$. Inverse $\mathbb{L}$ for the tensor product.

The last  two steps are universal constructions. This means that to define a monoidal functor $Mot_\sim(k)\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$, we just need a monoidal functor $R$ from the category of correspondance to $\mathcal{A}$ as long as $\mathcal{A}$ has kernels and images of projectors and such that $R(\mathbb{L})$ is invertible in $\mathcal{A}$.

And this is the case for the Hodge realization :

- Start with the functor $\mathcal{V}_k^{op}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}HS$ which sends $X$ to $\bigoplus_i H^i(X,\mathbb{Q})$ equipped with its canonical Hodge struture.
- If $c\in Corr^0_\sim(X,Y) $, we can define a pullback map $c^*:\bigoplus H^k(Y)\rightarrow\bigoplus H^k(X)$.
- The category of Hodge structure is abelian, in particular, it has kernels and images of projectors. We can extend our realization functor to the category of effective motives. Namely the motive $(h(X),p)$ is sent to $\operatorname{Im}p^*\subset \bigoplus H^k(X)$.
- Finally, the Lefschetz motive $\mathbb{L}$ is sent to $H^2(\mathbb{P}^1)=\mathbb{Z}(-1)$ which is a rank one Hodge structure and is in particular invertible. Hence we can extend the realization functor to the category of motives. Namely it will send $(h(x),p,n)$ to $\operatorname{Im}p^*\subset\bigoplus H^*(X)(-n)$.

It is important to know the following fact about the category of motives :
$$\operatorname{Hom}((h(X),p,m),(h(Y),q,n))=pCorr^{n-m}_\sim(X,Y)q$$
where $Corr^k_\sim(X,Y)=Z^{\operatorname{dim}X+k}(X\times Y)/\sim$.

In particular, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},(h(X),\operatorname{id},*))=Z^*(X)/\sim$.

On the other hand, in the category of Hodge structure $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},H^*(X))$ are the Hodge classes.

If the Hodge realization functor is full, we can deduce in particular that every Hodge classes comes from an algebraic cycle which is the statement of the Hodge conjecture.

The converse is not more difficult, if the Hodge conjecture hold, every Hodge classes in $H^*(X\times Y)$ is algebraic, but Hodge classes are in $H^*(X\times Y)$ are in bijection with morphisms of Hodge structures $H^*(X)\rightarrow H^*(Y)$. Thus the realization functor is full.

(The faithfulness just comes from the choice of the equivalence $\sim$ and has nothing to do with the Hodge conjecture)

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) Please, can you give me more explanations about your last sentence : ''The faithfulness just comes from the choice of the equivalence ∼ and has nothing to do with the Hodge conjecture'' even if the faithfulness has nothing to do with the Hodge conjecture ? I don't really understand it. Please !  :-)

Comment: The homological equivalence is defined to be the one such that the realization functor is faithful.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much Roland. :-)

Comment: You're welcome.