# Morphisms between pure Hodge Structures of smooth varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $k$ is a field which admits an embedding $\sigma:k \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. If $X$ is a smooth projective varieties over $k$, from Hodge theory there is a natural pure Hodge structure on
\begin{equation}
H^*(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})=\oplus_{i=0}^{2\text{dim}\,X}H^i(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})
\end{equation}
and we will also denote this pure Hodge structure by $H^*(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$. Suppose $Y$ is another smooth projective variety defined over $k$, the following post

[Why is the Hodge conjecture equivalent to the assertion that $ \mathcal{R}_{ \mathrm{Hodge} } $ is fully faithfull?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249701/why-is-the-hodge-conjecture-equivalent-to-the-assertion-that-mathcalr-ma)

seems to imply that any morphism (in the category of pure Hodge structures) from $H^*(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$ to $H^*(Y(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$ is induced by a Hodge class of $H^{2 \text{dim}\,X}((X \times_k Y)(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$, i.e. an element of $H^{2 \text{dim}\,X}((X \times_k Y)(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q}) \cap H^{ \text{dim}\,X,\text{dim}\,X}((X \times_k Y)(\mathbb{C}))$. E.g, a map $f: Y \rightarrow X$ determines a cycle $C^{\text{dim}\,X}(X \times_k Y)$, which induces a Hodge cycle that will give such a morphism.

Any one who can explain this claim?

Comment: For any $i$ morphism is given by weight zero elements of $(H^i(X,\mathbb{Q})^* \otimes H^i(Y,\mathbb{Q})$. Using poincare duality we get that this is isomorphic as hodge structure to $H^{2n-i}(X,\mathbb{Q}(n)) \otimes H^i(Y,\mathbb{Q})$. This is nothing but $H^{2n}(X \times Y, \mathbb{Q}(n))$. Now weight zero elements of this are the hodge classes, which more or less follows by definition.

Comment: @random123 Thank you very much and I understand now! I didn't realise that Poincare duality induces an isomorphism not only at cohomology groups level, but also at pure Hodge structure level.